# Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the surface $\rho=1+\cos\phi$

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the surface $\rho=1+\cos\phi$.
How do I set up the triple integral for this? I know that $1+\cos\theta$ is a cardioid but how would it look like as a surface?

Comment: It is the surface of revolution formed by rotating the cardioid.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is found by integrating $\iiint 1\cdot dV$. The real trick is in finding the bounds. The easiest way to do this would be to set up the integral order with the angle first:

$$V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}(\rho-1)} \rho^2\sin\phi \:d\phi d\rho d\theta $$

Comment: " The real trick is in finding the bounds. The easiest way to do this would be to set up the integral order with the angle first:".. why?

Comment: @Buraian just as we ask posters to put effort into their questions, we should put effort into quality comments. Would you care to explain your question further? I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe this is what the other comment was getting at - why not$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{1+\cos\phi}\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta\,?$$